# How bazel creates the third_party/py/numpy/numpy_include link?

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

bazel version
Build label: 0.3.1-homebrew

OS: Mac 10.12

During the build of the tensorflow I end up with the brokne link third_party/py/numpy/numpy_include pointing to a non-existed folder (I had removed numpy):

```
>  ls -l third_party/py/numpy/numpy_include
third_party/py/numpy/numpy_include -> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.11.2-py2.7-macosx-10.12-intel.egg/numpy/core/include
```

so I had to create a correct link manually:

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include third_party/py/numpy/numpy_include
```

Now the build is working again. However, I want to understand how the bazel creates the link and what is the correct way to update it after new version of the dependencies is installed.

Comment: Is that always reproducible? Since it's a build issue, please file an issue on our [github page](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues). Did you try after running `./configure` again?

Comment: I think the link is set up by `blaze fetch`.

Comment: yep, ```./configuration``` helps, as well as doing ```bazel clean```, have not tried ```blaze fetch``` though. Looks like bazel works as intended, however it would be nice to, somehow, check all the links before the build process. Also I do not think this is tensorflow related, I think this is bazel level issue.